# What's the significance of the bit group size in base64 or base32 encoding (RFC 4648)?

Tags: math, encoding

Why would they chose to use a 24-bit or 40-bit (that's really odd) bit group/word size for base 64 and base 32 respectively.

Specifically, can someone explain why the the least common multiple is significant?

```
lcm(log2(64), 8) = 24
lcm(log2(32), 8) = 40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base 64 encoding basically involves taking a stream of 8-bit bytes and transforming it to a stream of 6-bit characters that can be represented by printable ASCII characters.

Taking a single byte at a time means you have one 6 bit character with 2 bits left over.

Taking two bytes (16 bits) means you have two 6-bit characters with 4 bits left over.

Taking 3 bytes (24 bits) means you have three bytes that can be split exactly into 4 characters with no bits left over.

So the lcm of bytes size and character size is naturally the size you need to split your input into.

6 bit characters are chosen because this is the largest size that you can use printable ascii characters for all values. If you went up to 7 bits you would need non-printing characters.

The argument for base 32 is similar, but now you are using 5-bit characters, so the lcm of 8 and 5 is the word size. This character size allows for case insensitive printable characters, 6 bit characters require differentiating between upper and lower cases.

Comment: I was hoping for a bit more on a analysis of the LCM function. Specifically why `lcm(a,b)=(a*b)/gcd(a, b)` is the answer to this question (intuitively we can count and see that it is). However, how should we interpret this mathematically. If you have any thoughts to share on that it be most appreciated.